# Sprite collision AndEngine

Tags: animation, sprite, andengine

I want to update the position of my sprite. But it is moving downwards then jumps a little and then stops. It doesn't even move left or right. I want it to move left, right, up and down based on tilt.
Here is my code:-

```
Scene scene = new Scene();
        scene.setBackground(new Background(1.09804f, 0.6f, 3.0f));
        playerSprite = new AnimatedSprite(10, 10, 48, 64, pTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        playerSprite.animate(300);

    PhysicsWorld physicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2( 0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_MOON), false);

    FixtureDef PLAYER_FIX = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(10.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);

    Body playerBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, playerSprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, PLAYER_FIX);

    physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(playerSprite, playerBody, true, false));

    scene.attachChild(playerSprite);
```

Comment: Is there any one to help??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your

```
PhysicsWorld physicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2( 0, SensorManager.GRAVITY_MOON), false);
```

Change SensorManager.Gravity_Moon which makes a constant gravity pull directed down for all your objects - to .Sensor_Orientation. Im not sure which one exactly you have to choose but there is your problem. Try some other .Sensor_xxx if the one I told you doesn't work.

Comment: You should not use gravity, but sensor orientation, but I guess you already figured it out

Answer (score 0):

`public void onAccelerationChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
        // TODO Aiuto-generated method stub
        Vector2 gravity = Vector2Pool.obtain(pAccelerationData.getX(), pAccelerationData.getY());
        this.physicsWorld.setGravity(gravity);;
        Vector2Pool.recycle(gravity);`